# Setting titles in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the pivot function from Pandas. My intention is to aggregate values by taking the sum. Below you can see data and code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                         "small", "large", "small", "small",
                         "large"],
                   "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D','E'], index=['A'],
                    columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
```

So this function works well and gives good results. But after this new problem arise. Namely, now columns have double titles (e.g C/A, D/LARGE etc). You can see the table below

[image]

Now I want to have these titles in separate columns: **C_A, D_large,D_small, E_large and E_small**.

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the index name with the column name, then join the multiindex columns together

```
table.index.name = table.columns.names[-1] + '_' + table.index.name
table.columns = table.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Result:

```
>>> table
     D_large  D_small  E_large  E_small
C_A                                    
bar       11       11       15       17
foo        4        7        9       13
```

Comment: I wonder why they are not in the same line C_A together with D_large D_small E_large E_small

Comment: @silent_hunter how can they be? there's only four columns of data

Comment: The index, and its name, are intentionally separated from the columns, and their names, to make it clear they are not the same thing, but instead reference different attributes of the data structure, as @Derek O said